# Why is the alternative of fork() system call in python for windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my code which is not working in windows.what should i use in place of fork

```
import os

print("Process id before forking: {}".format(os.getpid()))

try:
    pid = os.fork()
except OSError:
    exit("Could not create a child process")

if pid == 0:
    print("In the child process that has the PID {}".format(os.getpid()))
    exit()

print("In the parent process after forking the child {}".format(pid))
finished = os.waitpid(0, 0)
print(finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

The python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module is universal and may be useful for you. For further reading, check out this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/).

Also, Cygwin recreated it, but I wouldn't recommend it simply because of how difficult it is to implement, however, if you wish to learn about it, here is the [link](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process).

Comment: but it doesn't know anything about fork. The error in log says.                               pid = os.fork()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'fork'